# How much will the height of the water level rise when Satoshi immerses a saké bottle with diameter 7.5 cm?

Tags: geometry

I've been struggling with this problem for an hour and I have *no* idea how to start it:

> Satoshi likes warm saké. He places 1 litre of water in a sauce pan
> with diameter 17 cm. How much will the height of the water level rise when
> Satoshi immerses a saké bottle with diameter 7.5 cm?
>
> Hint: You’ll need the volume conversion ratio 1 litre = 1000 cm³

So far this section of the book had simple geometry problems. My intuition tells me this is more of a physics problem, and the Archimedes principle comes to my mind. I know there must be a way though.

(1) Could someone point me in the right direction without actually solving the problem?
(2) Could someone solve the problem (and let me know he/she is going to solve it) in case (1) is not enough?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on how much height of the bottle is below the surface of the water

Comment: And on the shape of the bottle and that of the sauce pan.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of water initially is equal to the area of the pan, multiplied by the initial height.
$$V=A_p\cdot h_0=\pi R^2h_0$$
When you put the bottle in, I assume that it goes all the way to the bottom. The water in the pan will now raise to $h_1$. The volume of the water is $$V=(A_p-A_b)\cdot h_1=\pi(R^2-r^2)h_1$$
Here $R=17/2\ cm$, $r=7.5/2\ cm$, and $V=1000\ cm^3$. You can find $h_0$ and $h_1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume the bottle is cylindrical and tall enough to continue above the surface of the water, even after immersion, all you need to know is that the base has changed from a circle of diameter 17 to an annulus (flat washer shape), outer diameter 17 and inner diameter 7.5. How many square centimeters are there in this smaller base?